# How can I calculate the difference between 2 numbers

Tags: c

How can I calculate the diffrence between 2 Numbers in % in c? I have written my own exp funktion and want to compare it with the original one from the math.h.

this is my exp funktion and I want to compare the result with the exp() from math.h and print the difference in percent.

```
double expo(double zahl)
{
    int schleifendurchlaeufe = 1;
    double exp = 1;//Variable in der das Ergebnis steht
    double sum = 1;//Summant, der auf exp raufaddiert wird

    do
    {
        sum = sum * (zahl / schleifendurchlaeufe);
        exp = exp + sum;
        schleifendurchlaeufe++;
    } while (exp != exp + sum);

    return exp;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your `own exp funktion`.

Comment: How would you do it with mathematics?

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, have a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question with code examples so we can help more.

Comment: thats my main problem, I think I can do it in c if I have the correct math solution.

Comment: Then you need to find the correct mathematical solution. Stack overflow is not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: BTW: When `zahl < 0`, the cancellation caused by + and - terms limits precision.  Better to add `if (x < 0) return 1.0/expo(-zahl);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"difference between 2 Numbers in %" sounds strange, perhaps you want percentage difference (see explanation at https://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html)

For case of comprising only results of exp function (two positive values) you can use the following function:

```cpp
double percdiffcalc(double a, double b)
{
    double difference = abs(a - b);
    double average = (a + b) / 2.0;
    return difference * 100.0 / average;
}
```

You can call this function for any two values, e.g. `percdiffcalc(myexp(x), exp(x));`

Comment: thanks VolAnd, the only line i dont get is: double difference = abs (a-b);, where come the abs from and what does it mean

Comment: Rather than using the integer function `abs()`, better to use the `double` function `fabs()`.  `difference = fabs(a - b);` found in `<math.h>`.

Comment: Yes, in c it is `fabs`... I just forgot c++ and c gifferences

Comment: Now I got it, this funktion is to get the absolute value. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs